# How to serialize and deserialize collection of custom type using Json.Net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Assume I have a custom type like below:

```cs
public class Foo{
    public Foo (string str) => Value = str.ToLower();

    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And a custom JsonConverter for it:

```cs
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo> {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => writer.WriteValue(value.Value);

    public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => new(reader.Value as string);
}
```

Now I have another class containing a collection of `Foo` using attributes for serialization:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Bar{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
    [DataMember(Name = "foo")]
    public Foo Foo {get; set;}

    [JsonConverter(typeof(???))]
    [DataMember(Name = "foos")]
    public List<Foo> Foos {get; set;}
}
```

Could I possibly make use of the `FooConverter` I've already implemented in `JsonConverterAttribute`, or I have to write another `FooListConverter` to handle such serialization?

Comment: How sample json looks? Did you tried not to use `JsonConverter` attribute for list at all? Did you tried to pass Converter fx as parameter of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` or register it globally ?

Comment: @Selvin I'd like to make use of `FooConverter` in `JsonConverterAttribute`, or briefly speaking, fill the three question marks in `Bar`. In this example, a sample JSON may look like `{"foo":"Foo", "foos":["foos1","foos2"]}`

Comment: [also, as I wrote in first comment it works fine if you add converter](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gBtphm) .. and basically the question doesn't make sens **as obviously you have to put  type derived from `JsonConverter<List<Foo>>`  as `???`** to use `JsonConverter` attribute

Comment: [... and code from duplicated question also works ...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ErUjJR)

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your navigation, the answer to that question solved my problem precisely